# Correction for multiple observations for the same variable in R analysis

Tags: r, modeling, biostatistics

I have a dataframe of pre- and post-treatment serum lipid levels from 9 patients that I am trying to analyze in R. I want to see if a patient's baseline lipid level can predict the response to a class of medication, however, I am running into an issue where some patients received two different drugs and showed different responses to each drug. Below is an example of the dataset:

```
    id prepost    lipid    conc  treatment_x  treatment_y  treatment_x_y_combo          
  1  1     pre  lipid x   36097           NR            R                   NA                       
  2  2     pre  lipid x   17667           NR           NR                   NA                       
  3  3     pre  lipid x   17949           NR            R                   NA                       
  4  4     pre  lipid x   18839           NR            R                   NA                       
  5  5     pre  lipid x   10965           NR           NA                   NA                       
  6  6     pre  lipid x   40371           NA            R                   NA                       
  7  7     pre  lipid x   38086           NA            R                   NA                       
  8  8     pre  lipid x  118650           NA            R                   NA                       
  9  9     pre  lipid x   58279           NA           NA                   NR
```

For context, treatment x and treatment y are both in the same treatment class.

To answer my question, I was planning to run a t-test between responders (R) and non-responders (NR), I'm afraid I can't simply label each patient as an R or NR because some patients received two different drugs and showed two different responses to each drug. For example, id 1 received treatment x and y. They didn't respond to treatment x but responded to treatment y.

I tried to focus on just one treatment (i.e. treatment x) rather than the class of treatment, but it appears that all patients that received treatment x did not respond and all patients that received drug y responded, except for one.

I'm relatively new to R and data analysis in general, so I apologize if I am not explaining any of this correctly. I was hoping someone had any suggestions as to what I should do next. Is there a way to transform the data to correct the issue of different responses to different drugs? Or is there a test I could run that would take the multiple observations into account?

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in some sort of logistic regression that will allow you to predict the response of a binary response variable from your continuous predictor. Here it would be multivariate logistic regression because you're trying to predict multiple outcomes from the same predictor, but I don't know how to explicitly model that and your small sample size will make it tricky to trust the results.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more details about the design of the study and its time course. It's not clear how you distinguished responders from non responders or whether treatments x and y were given at the same time, or at different times, and if at different times in which order. Also, how many different lipids were measured? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.